# Factorising $x^3+2x^2-c^3-2c^2$

Tags: factoring

How would you go about factorising this?

I mean how would you go from this first line to the next line?

(what step goes on between these lines?)

$x^3+2x^2 -c^3-2c^2$

$= (x-c)(c^2+cx+2c+x^2+2x)$

Comment: Hint: $(x^3-c^3)+2(x^2-c^2)$.

Comment: I got to this stage before but couldn't reach past it, I will give it a go again

Comment: Remember $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b + \cdots + b^{n-1})$.

Comment: It should be apparent by inspection that $x-c$ is a factor, so use polynomial long division to get the quotient. (Synthetic division could also be used). One could also proceed by writing the first term as $(x+1)^2x-x$ and similarly for the second term; the resulting difference of squares can be factored, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

First see that $c$ is a root of the polynomial in $x$ you have (that is: $c^3 + 2c^2 - c^3 -2c^2 = 0$). Therefore you can factor $(x-c)$. Then using [Horner's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) you get your factorisation.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^3-c^3)+2(x^2-c^2)=(x-c)(x^2+cx+c^2)+2(x-c)(x+c)$$
$$(x-c)(x^2+cx+c^2+2(x+c))=(x-c)(x^2+(c+2)x+c^2+2c)$$